How to locally test sub routes for a basic Javascript router in VS Code and the extension Live Server?
I have an AWS Cloudfront function that redirects urls to several different html pages hosted in S3 along the lines of this:
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    if (uri.split('/')[1] == '') {
        request.uri = '/index.html';
    } else if (uri.split('/')[1] == 'contact'){
        request.uri = '/contact.html';
    } else if (uri.split('/')[1] == 'blog'){
        request.uri = '/blog.html';
    } else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri = '/index.html';
    }
    return request;
}

This works fine but I want to build the site locally using VS Code and test using the Live Server extension with my 3 html files in the root directory but have sub routes point to them.

http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html
http://127.0.0.1:5500/blog/index.html
http://127.0.0.1:5500/contact/index.html

These are the sub routes:
www.example.com
www.example.com/index.html
route to: /index.html

www.example.com/foo
www.example.com/foo/123
www.example.com/foo/abc
www.example.com/foo/def/123
route to: /foo/index.html

www.example.com/bar
www.example.com/bar/123
www.example.com/bar/abc
www.example.com/bar/def/123
route to: /bar/index.html

Effectively I want to be able to use VS Code similar to this to read the pathArray values so I can change page content locally based on the pathname.  Basically blog/hello would show the blog page hello whereas /blog would show the blog list:
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');


Is this question how to configure your local server? The question is unclear. How is this related to VS Code?

No it's how to route sub routes to a single HTML page within VS Code using Live Server. Be great if it's not downvoted seeing there isn't single answer on stackoverflow explaining how to do it like this.

Why do you post an answer that describes how to configure your local server if that's not the question? "No it's how to route sub routes to a single HTML page within VS Code using Live Server." How is this not a server configuration?  If that's the correct answer, your question is off-topic and not about programming. It should be posted on Super User or Server Fault

Given that the question is about how to locally develop using Javascript routes in html using vscode I think I am in the right place.  There are 16,456 vscode questions and 1,000's related to vscode settings and over 600 related to the extension I have a question about.  That's versus 2 on stack exchange and 8 on server fault.  I have to respectively disagree. It's even mirroring the behavior of the AWS CloudFront function handler code locally which another 99 people have posted about here.

As you can see in your answer, your question has nothing to do with programming. The answer is a server configuration. You may need this server to test your code, but that doesn't make it a programming question. If I want to install Linux for coding and I have a problem with the installation, it's not a programming question. There are many off-topic questions on Stack Overflow, but that's not a reason to add another one.

I found a solution in a GitHub ticket here.
Effectively you need to amend your VS Code user settings.json, on Linux mine was here:
Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

To define your sub routes using liveServer.settings.mount to point to specific HTML pages like this:
{
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.mount": [
        ["/ ", "./index.html"],
        ["/foo", "./foo.html"],
        ["/bar", "./bar.html"],
    ]
}

http://localhost:5500/foo/abc would now correctly route to /foo and abc is available as pathArray[2] using var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
